# Why does the Dude look like he does?

Tags: plot-explanation, free-guy

In Free Guy, a character referred to as the Dude is placed in the city. The role is played by Ryan Reynolds who also plays (Blue Shirt) Guy. As Guy is just one of many NPC's and the Dude was still being written and programmed, why would they both just happen to look alike?

Comment: ["Antwan then sends Dude, a bigger and unfinished copy of Guy developed for Free City 2, into the game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Guy)

Comment: @BCdotWEB but that's just a wikisummary written by someone summarizing what he saw in the film. That doesn't explain why the Dude happens to be in the form of Guy when there seems to be no other duplication of NPC characters.

Answer (score 5):

When Guy starts leveling up, he quickly becomes famous and popular. Antwan, wanting to capitalize on Guy's popularity, demands that a Blue Shirt Guy be added to Free City 2.  So the team creates Dude with all the "upgrades" that Antwan wanted added.

Comment: I do recall that Antwan yelled at the art people to capitalize on the Blue Shirt guy popularity, but I didn't see anywhere where that was specifically impacting Dude (and the time flow of the movie has so much happen so quickly that it is weird to think that in this one particular area, this singular chnage was made).